# Unable to assign activities in androidmanifest.xml as required for correct activity sequence

Tags: android

Intro - Sequence

1. Welcome Activity (only once per user first time open)
2. No internet connectivity (Check at time of launch of application)
3. Main Activity (Launch of application)

Current androidmanifest.xml sequence -

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.no_internet_alert"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".MainActivity"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Comment: What you want to do ? Can you explain bit more ?

Comment: Here welcome activity (4 introductory sliders) - is not working. no error in code shows and if no_internet_alert code was removed it works fine. Unable to get the welcome slider.

Comment: Hi, you should provide more context and details in your question, directly in your post. This will help you to get better answer ! Feel free to check out the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), this will help you understand how to properly ask (remember that context is key !)

Comment: Thanks will do the same next time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.no_internet_alert"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

 </activity>
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: It's showing an error of closed tags. Can you check it once, please?

Comment: Thanks. Checked but here no internet activity & the Main activity working fine. The issue was with the welcome activity is not working as required.